# Stuck Creating a Database Programatically. Using Xcode 3.1.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode3.1

```
{    
    NSString *docsDir; 
    NSArray *dirPaths; 
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 

    docsDir=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dirPaths[0]];


    databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"contacts.db"]]; 

    NSFileManager *filemgr = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:databasePath]; 

    const   char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String]; 

    if (sqlite3_open (dbpath,  &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)   
    {
        theStatus = @"asss";

        if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO) 
        { 

            char *errMsg; 
            const char *sql_stmt = 
            "CREATE   TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, ADDRESS TEXT,PHONE TEXT)";

            if (sqlite3_exec(contactDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg)== SQLITE_OK) 
            {           
                theStatus.text = @"database and table created"; 
            } 
            else {
                theStatus.text = @"Failed to open/create database"; 
            }       
        }

    }
   [filemgr release];}

}
```

Comment: Just a small heads up, if you plan to submit you app to the Apple App Store you need to Xcode 5.1.1 Apple no longer accepts any Apps build with older Xcode version.

Comment: I am trying this code for myself.if any better solution for this problem please help me

Comment: What does `errMsg` say when it fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
-(void)databasecreation{

// Get the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

// Build the path to the database file
databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"contacts.db"]];

NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

//check the database is exist
if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO)
{

    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        char *errMsg;

        const char * sql_stmt = [@"CREATE   TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, ADDRESS TEXT,PHONE TEXT)" UTF8String];


        if (sqlite3_exec(contactDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK){
            NSLog(@"Failed to create tables");
        }
        sqlite3_close(contactDB);

    } else {
        NSLog( @"Failed to open/create database");
    }
}
}
```

**Update**

This one works for me

appdelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "sqlite3.h"


@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>{
    sqlite3 *contactDB;
    NSString *databasePath;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic,readonly) sqlite3 *contactDB;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *databasePath;

@end
```

appdelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize contactDB,databasePath;
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self databasecreation];
    return YES;
}
-(void)databasecreation{

    // Get the documents directory
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    // Build the path to the database file
    databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"contacts.db"]];

    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    //check the database is exist
    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO)
    {

        const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            char *errMsg;

            const char * sql_stmt = [@"CREATE   TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, ADDRESS TEXT,PHONE TEXT)" UTF8String];


            if (sqlite3_exec(contactDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK){
                NSLog(@"Failed to create tables");
            }
            sqlite3_close(contactDB);

        } else {
            NSLog( @"Failed to open/create database");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Noe i am using your code,but the same answer "failed to open/create database" please help me

Comment: 1) Why alloc a new string for `databasePath`? 2) Log `errMsg` for any failures or call `sqlite3_errmsg`.